# How can I start a subprocess in Python, such that it connects I/O to the parent using pty instead of pipes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

> How can I start a subprocess in Python, such that it connects I/O to the parent using pty instead of pipes?

I need the subprocess, running a C application, to connect I/O to the parent using pty instead of pipes.

The reason is that C applications buffer their output, when connected using pipes, and I have no control over source-code to flush stdout.

I've looked over the subprocess module, but I cannot find such option. In particular, the `shell=True` parameter of `Popen.subprocess()` doesn't work as I'd expected.

Any ideas?

Comment: See the `pty` module that is build on `os.openpty`.

Comment: Would you elaborate in an answer? :)